# From Onclick inline to Function code issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to move some inline code into a function.

This Works:

```
<img onclick="window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Mesasage: ' + $('#divA').html() +' - '+$('#divB').html()+' cars - '+$('#males_count_pecentage').html()+' bikes', 'subject here', 'http://mysite/image.png', 'http://abc.go.com')" src="images/share_text.png" style="height:2em" />
```

But when I do this:

```
function myfunc() {

    alert('hello');
    window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Mesasage: ' + $('#divA').html() +' - '+$('#divB').html()+' cars - '+$('#males_count_pecentage').html()+' bikes', 'subject here', 'http://mysite/image.png', 'http://abc.go.com');

}
```

and this call it from the function:

```
<img onclick="myfunc();" src="images/share_text.png" style="height:2em" />
```

Nothing happens.

I'm I forgetting something here?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: did you got the alert???

Comment: None at all? It doesn't complain about the way the function is being defined? It doesn't complain that myfunc doesn't exist after you click the image? AND it doesn't work? That seems pretty unlikely.

Comment: Images are not supposed to be interactive. This won't fix your problem, but put the onclick on a `<button>` and the image inside that.

Comment: It's working as you can see it [**here**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqGpQB), and alerts "hello", so the function is called perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I just tested it in the browser. It seems to work. Maybe you have included the function false. I just postet a short code statement in this post. Feel free to try it out!

```html
<script>
function myfunc() {

    alert('hello');
    window.plugins.socialsharing.share('Mesasage: ' + $('#divA').html() +' - '+$('#divB').html()+' cars - '+$('#males_count_pecentage').html()+' bikes', 'subject here', 'http://mysite/image.png', 'http://abc.go.com');
}
</script>
<img onclick="myfunc();" src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSWtE_a5B3SFO386Eq9H0g5GklQUrwkXo64UsiLKgsGvFQZe937" style="height:2em" />
```